# C# random value from dictionary and tuple

Tags: c#, random, dictionary, tuples

I have the following code, and need to get a random item that contains the string "Region_1" from the dictionary.

```
public static Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, int, CurrencyType>> ItemArray = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, int, CurrencyType>>()
{
     { 0xB3E, new Tuple<string, int, CurrencyType>("Region_1", 1500, CurrencyType.Fame) }
};

public static int GenerateItemID(string ShopID)
{
     var GeneratedItem = ItemArray.ElementAt(new Random().Next(0, ItemArray.Count)).Key;

}
```

How do I select this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really possible to this all that efficiently...

First create a static `Random` at class level... this will prevent [non-random behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number) if you run the query frequently over a short period of time... (it's seeded from a *discrete* clock)

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
```

then:

```
var item = ItemArray.Values
   .Where(t => t.Item1 == ShopID)
   .OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next())
   .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: +1. Note that performance of the method is O(n) due to need to search through all items - unordered dictionary not helping here.